# ListView doesn't populate values from the ListModel

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make a list of buttons, where the user can select one of the options. I can't seem to display the text from the listmodel, but I can't figure out why. It seems like even the button is not correctly placed. Does anyone have ideas as to how to fix this? Thanks!

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 400; height: 400

        ListView {
            id: listview
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: timeList
            delegate: Item {
                anchors.top: parent.top
                height: 30
                Button {
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    id: textButton
                    text: text
                    width: parent.width
                    height: 30
                    flat: true
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log(value)
                    }
                }
                Rectangle {
                    height: (index === timeList.count - 1 ? 0 : 1)
                    color: '#E1E6E9'
                    width: 400
                    anchors {
                        left: textButton.left
                        top: textButton.bottom
                    }
                }
            }
            ListModel {
                id: timeList
                ListElement { text: "15 minutes"; value: 15 }
                ListElement { text: "1 hour"; value: 60 }
                ListElement { text: "3 hours"; value: 180 }
                ListElement { text: "6 hours"; value: 360 }
                ListElement { text: "12 hours"; value: 720 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't affect the text, but the `Item` in your delegate should not have `anchors.top` set. The ListView will take care of positioning each delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- don't name `ListElement` properties using keywords, `text: text` looks confusing.
- don't wrap everything with `Rectangle`/`Item` with no need, use `Layout` instead if needed
- never use anchors for delegates
- pay attention that all containers have a size, the delegate's `Item` has no with for example (or probably 0)

actually, that should work:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: timeList
        delegate: Button {
            id: textButton
            text: name
            width: parent.width
            height: 30
            flat: true
            onClicked: {
                console.log(value)
            }
        }
        ListModel {
            id: timeList
            ListElement { name: "15 minutes"; value: 15 }
            ListElement { name: "1 hour"; value: 60 }
            ListElement { name: "3 hours"; value: 180 }
            ListElement { name: "6 hours"; value: 360 }
            ListElement { name: "12 hours"; value: 720 }
        }
    }
}
```